# How to find integer solutions of curves of the form $b^3-a^3=3c$?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, integers

I was trying to figure out over which intervals $[a,b]$ the definite integral of $x^2:$ $$\int_a^bx^2dx=\frac{b^3}{3}-\frac{a^3}{3} = c $$ is an integer $c$, and further, does there exist any of those intervals $[a,b]$ for which $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}?$

That is, how do I find integer solutions to curves of the form $b^3-a^3=3c$ for $c\in\mathbb{Z},$ assuming there are any at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can write $b^3-a^3 = (b-a)(b^2+ab+a^2)$. For all integer value of $a$ and $k$, you can take $b = a+3k$ so that $b^3-a^3$ is divisible by 3. This gives you an integer value for $c$. Here are some values for the triple $[a,b,c]$.

$$ \left[ -4 , -1 , 21 \right] 
  , \left[ -3 , 0 , 9 \right] 
  , \left[ -2 , 1 , 3 \right] 
  , \left[ -1 , 2 , 3 \right] 
  , \left[ 0 , 3 , 9 \right] 
  , \left[ 1 , 4 , 21 \right] 
  , \left[ 2 , 5 , 39 \right] 
  , \left[ 3 , 6 , 63 \right] 
  , \left[ 4 , 7 , 93 \right] 
  $$